# Help with mixed model in R

Tags: regression, mixed-model

I'm trying to apply regression on my data and I would like to be sure to do it correctly.
My dependent variable (DV) is the position of the subject (numeric value).
My independent variables (IV) are :

- The group in which the subject is (2 groups, a subject is in one or the other)
- The type of stimulus (2 different types, each subject is confronted with each stimulus so it is a "within" variable)
- The time of the measure (each subject got measured 3 times for each stimulus, so 6 times in total)
  I'm interested in each principal effect and the triple interaction (not the doubles).

If I'm correct, I have 1 between-subject IV (the group) and 2 within-subject crossed IV (stim and time).
My dataframe counts 6 columns:

- The NS column gives the number of the subject.
- The Pos column which gives the subject's position
- The Group column
- The Stim column (the type of stimulus).
- The Time column (the moment of measurement; coded -0.5, 0 and 0.5)

Here is the code I ran in R :

```
RegAlc <- lmer(Pos ~ Group + Time + Stim + Group:Time:Task +
                     (Time*Stim|NS), data = d)
summary(RegAlc)
```

The code works but I would like to be sure that this is the correct way to analyze these data.

Thank you very much!

Comment: (+1 to @Dimitris) plus It’s unclear what Task is and why it’s only included in an interaction.

Answer (score 4):

It is not clear whether the `Pos` outcome variable is a continuous random variable, resulting in error terms having the normal distribution. Note that this is an assumption behind the linear mixed model you are fitting with `lmer()`.

Regarding the structure of the model,

- You have included the main effects of `Group`, `Time` and `Stim`, and their three-way interaction, without including the two-way interactions. Typically, this is not done. Moreover, interaction terms are complex terms requiring sufficiently large sample size to estimate them stably. This holds for two-way interactions, and even more for three-way ones. Are you certain that you want to include all these interaction terms?
- The random-effects part is often build using a build-up approach, starting from random intercepts, i.e., `(1 | NS)`, then including random slopes, i.e., `(Time | NS)`, and performing a likelihood ratio test (using the `anova()` function) to see if the fit of the model is improved. You could continue to include more complex random-effects terms. But note that often the dependencies in the data are not that complex to support including many/complex random-effects terms. Trying to fit a mixed model with such a complex structure may result in unstable estimated and boundary problems (i.e., the same variances of the random effects are estimated to be zero).

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answers! I will try this way! (Pos is a continuous variable normally distributed so application's condition should be ok)